# Data sent to server-side via AJAX POST request does not persist

Tags: php, ajax, session, post

I'm creating an application in PHP which programmatically sends a POST request from within the home.php file as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: home.php,
    data: {id: 5 },
    success: function(data) {    
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

The alert function shows the expected output:

```
array(1){
  ["id"] => string(1) "5"
}
...
```

but when I include

```
<?php
   var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

I get unsatisfactory results, which suggest that none of the data I'm sending from the client-side to the server side is persisting:

```
array(0) { }
```

I have also tried establishing sessions and updating session variables through the posted data, but in this case the modified session variable does not get echoed to the client after the POST request.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["varname"] = "green";

    echo $_SESSION["varname"];
?>
```

echoes "green", as expected.

```
<?php

    $_SESSION["varname"] = $_POST["id"];
    echo $_SESSION["varname"];
?>
```

echoes nothing.

Comment: Both `<?php?`, `<?php>` are syntactically invalid as is `url: home.php` in your JS. They should be `<?php` and `url: 'home.php'` respectively

Comment: It was syntactically correct in the original code, and the edits have been made. To anyone who downvotes, please inform me as to why so that I can understand what my mistake(s) were.

Comment: Can you confirm the correct POST data is being sent in your browser's *Network* console? Also, `url: home.php` is still incorrect unless you have an object `home` with a string URL property `php`

Comment: For debugging, you should enable full error messages at the top of your PHP script ~ `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL); ...`

Comment: The php file that I'm working on is called home.php, and in the url property I hav the entire url listed. Essentially I want the data to be sent to the page I'm currently on. After inspection of the Network console, it does not appear that the POST data is being sent.

Comment: @Phil I turned on errors and it notified me that "id" in $_POST["id"] is undefined. var_dump(_$POST) still yields array(0) {}

Comment: That's what you'd expect if there was no POST data being sent. Is it making a POST request at all? Are there any JS errors in your browser console?

Comment: No JS errors from Chrome Dev tools, and the alert function from the success property from the original AJAX call is propagated, so it looks like the POST is being dispatched from the client-side properly but the data is not being handled properly on the server-side.